# Hybrid Flutter / Swift App Shows Launch Screen

Tags: swift, flutter

I have inherited an App where on iOS the Authentication is written in Swift and the rest in Flutter.

When the app is launched UILaunchStoryboardName launch screen is shown as expected.

However when authentication is completed and the app calls Flutter the ios launchscreen is shown again.

I cannot find where this is coded or documented.

Is there a way not to show the launchscreen when Flutter is launched

App is using   "flutterSdkVersion": "3.10.6",

```
destinationVC = CustomFlutterViewController(project: nil, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
if let destVC = destinationVC {
   containedNavigationController.setViewControllers([destVC], animated: false)
}



import Foundation
import Flutter
import FlutterPluginRegistrant

class CustomFlutterViewController: FlutterViewController {
    
    override init(project: FlutterDartProject?, nibName: String?, bundle nibBundle: Bundle?) {
        super.init(project: project, nibName: nibName, bundle: nibBundle)
        
        if let engine = engine {
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: engine)
            AppManager.shared.startFlutterManager(engine: engine)
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/ios-flutterviewcontroller-splashscreenview-nullable

I can set FlutterViewController to splashScreenView which gives me a black screen when moving to Flutter.

or I can do something like

```
splashScreenView = GreenView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

But I cannot stop it all altogether